# Return the array containing the heights of the students from left to right in the line

Tags: c

In a school students are ordered to seat according to their height in a line they always choose their positions randomly to displeasure their teacher,one morning the teacher noticed their seating positions, and that he will be checking their positions in the next morning to make sure they are exactly the same.

Each student only remember one thing from that morning: the number of student to his left that were taller then him there are N students, each with a different height between 1 to n using this information you must reconstruct the seating arrangement from that morning.

You are given a int[], the ith element of which represents the number of taller student to the left of the student with height i (where i is a 1-based index). Return a int[] containing the heights of the students from left to right in the line.

Note: The input is guaranteed to produce a valid and unique output.

Inputs Specifications: 
your function should accept the fallowing inputs: 
Input 1: N 
Input 2: An array(left[]) of n integers

Output Specifications: 
you need to return the int [] containing the heights of the students from left to right in the line.

Example :

Input:

input 1: 4

input 2: {2,1,1,0}

Output: {4,2,1,3}

Explanation: 
Student of height 1 remembered there were 2 Students taller than him to his left. 
Student of height 2 remembered there were 1 Students taller than him to his left. 
Student of height 3 remembered there were 1 Students taller than him to his left. 
Student of height 4 remembered there were no Students taller than him to his left.

Below is my code:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<string.h>

  int* uniqueValue(int input1,int input2[])
  {
    int left, current;
    static int arr[4] = {0};
    int i      = 0;

      for(i=0;i<input1;i++)
       {
          current = input2[i];
          left    = 0;

          if(current > 0)
          left    = arr[(current-1)];

       if(left == 0 && arr[current] == 0)
        {
        arr[current] = input1-current;
        }
        else
    {
        for(int j=(i+1);j<input1;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] == 0)
            {
                left = arr[(j-1)];
                arr[j] = left - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}


return arr;
 }
```

My output is not as desired how can I improve my code for the same.

Comment: “My output is not as desired”, how?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Output should be {4,2,1,3} the above program gives output : {4,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0........,0}

Comment: Your code is either [c] or it is [c++]? Which compiler did you use to compile it?

Comment: Why do you include `string.h` when you don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to come up with my own solution for the problem, since I couldn't have a quick understanding of yours. I hope it helps. I tested it against your case scenario and another one I made up, and it worked for both.

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int* get_line_order(int in1, int *in2);

 int main()
 {
     int in[] = {7,0,1,4,3,1,0,1,1,0};
     int *out;
     int N = 10;

     out = get_oringinal(N, in);

     for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
         cout << out[i] << endl;

     return 0;
 }

 int* get_line_order(int in1, int *in2)
 {
     int *out = new int[in1];
     int i,j,k, count;

     //initializes out array
     for(i=0; i<in1; i++)
         out[i] = in1;

     //loops through in2
     for(i=0; i< (in1-1); i++)
     {
         count = 0;
         //loops through out
         for(j=0; j< (in1-1); j++)
         {
             if(out[j] > (i+1))
                 count++;
             if(count == in2[i])
             {
                 for(k = j+1; k<in1; k++)
                     if(out[k] == in1)
                     {
                         out[k] = i+1;
                         break;
                     }
                 break;
             }
             else if(count > in2[i])
             {
                 for(k = j; k<in1; k++)
                     if(out[k] == in1)
                     {
                         out[k] = i+1;
                         break;
                     }
                 break;
             }
         }
     }

     return out;
 }
```